# PHP routing with Codeigniter (Titles in URL)

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

How to remove the controller/method for cleaner URL in codeigniter?

What I´m doing now is the following:

```
http://localhost/Riads_Blog/welcome/blog_details/8
```

where *8* is the *blog id* getting from database by parameter `blog_id`.

---

How can I make my URL look like

```
http://localhost/Riads_Blog/blog_title
```

where `blog_title` is the title of the `blog_id=8`?

Comment: [This](http://www.jamesstoddern.net/seo-friendly-urls-in-codeigniter-the-challenge.html) is a great guide to get you started.

Comment: [https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html]